# Error converting parameter in C++

Tags: c++

Header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

const unsigned MaxLength = 11;

class Phone {
public:

    Phone(const char *phone) {
    setPhone(phone);
    }

    void        setPhone(const char Phone[ ]);
    const char* getPhone();

private:
    char phone[MaxLength+1];
};
```

Cpp file

```
#include "Phone.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib> 

using namespace std; 
bool checkNum(const char* num);

void Phone::setPhone(const char Phone[ ]) {
    strncpy(phone, Phone, MaxLength);
    phone[MaxLength] = '\0';
}

const char* Phone::getPhone() {
    return phone;
}


int main() {
    Phone i1("12345678901");

    cout << i1.getPhone() << endl;
    if (checkNum(i1.getPhone())) 
        cout << "Correct" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "Invalid Wrong" << endl;

}

bool checkNum(const char* num) {
    bool flag = true;
        if (atoi(num[0]) == 0)
            flag = false;
    return flag;
}
```

When I tried to compile, I get this error:

> error C2664: 'atoi' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from 'const char' to
>   'const char *' 1>        Conversion
>   from integral type to pointer type
>   requires reinterpret_cast, C-style
>   cast or function-style cast

I am trying to read the first element of the array as an int so I can compare it using the atoi function. I am having a parameter mismatch but I can't find where it is. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`atoi` requires a string as an input parameter, however `num[0]` is an `char`. Hence the error. You can simply use `int n = num[0] - '0'` to get the integer value (assuming num contains all numbers only).

Answer (score 2):

[atoi](http://man.cx/atoi) takes `"a string"` and not a `'c'`har:

```
 if (atoi(num[0]) == 0)  // <- here
```

Do you want to test if the first character is a '0'?

```
 if (num[0] == '0') { /* ... */ }
```

Do you want convert single chars to numbers `0 - 9`?

```
 int i = num[0] - '0'; // every i not beeing 0 - 9 is not a number.
```

Do you want to just check **if** `num[0]` is a number?

```
 #include <ctype.h>

 if (isdigit(num[0])) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: is there any predefined function or another way of converting a char to a int then?

Comment: I am trying to convert it to a int because I need to do some addition from the numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to convert a char to an int if you are sure its a number:

```
char* str = "012345";
int i = str[0] - 48; // Numbers start at 48 in ASCII table
if ( i==0 )
{ ... }
```